# Bash command to merge two rows data

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, text, multiple-columns

I have a three-column data file, and I want to do some transformation on the data for plot using bash. Notice it is not always `withop` first. In sometimes, the `noop` row can be first
The sample data is:

```
printff withop     1
printff noop     0
partial_sums withop     1
partial_sums noop     1
fasta noop     1
fasta withop     1
word_anagrams withop     2
word_anagrams noop     2
list noop     0
list withop     8
gc_mb withop     1
gc_mb noop     1
simple_connect withop     0
simple_connect noop     0
binary_trees noop     2
binary_trees withop     2
cal noop     3
cal withop     6
```

The transformation I want is to merge every two rows with same value of first column. The new format is still three columns, and the second column is withop and the third is noop. For example, the new data is:

```
printff  1   0
partial_sums   1 1
....
list    8   0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on related lines coming in pairs, here's a single-pass `awk` solution:

```
awk '{
  op1=$2; val1=$3
  getline
  val2=$3
  print $1 " " (op1 == "withop" ? val1 " " val2 : val2 " " val1)
}' file
```

- `op1=$2; val1=$3` reads the operation field (`$2`, the second whitespace-separated field) into var. `op1`, and the value field (`$3`, the third field) into var. `val1`.
- `getline` reads the next line from the input file, which causes *its* fields to be reflected in `$1`, ...

  - <sup>While use of `getline` is fine in this particular case - the lines can assumed to be *paired* - it has many pitfalls, and its use is rarely the right choice - see http://awk.info/?tip/getline</sup>
- `val2=$3` then stores the second line's value field in var. `val2`.
- `print $1 " " (op1 == "withop" ? val1 " " val2 : val2 " " val1)` then prints a single output line for the two lines at hand:

  - `$1`, the 1st field, is by definition the same on both lines, so we can use the 2nd line's value.
  - `(op1 == "withop" ? val1 " " val2 : val2 " " val1)` is a C-style ternary operator (inline conditional) that simply either prints the 1st line's value before the 2nd line's or vice versa, depending on whether the first line's operation field was `withop` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is always correct:

```
cat data.txt | sort | while read a b c && read d e f; do echo $a $c $f; done
```

Update: sorting added, as whithop and noop rows can be in any order.

Comment: The records has order. Sometimes it is ``withop`` first and ``op`` next while others are opposite.

Comment: Simple and effective, but, as with any solution involving `bash` loops, performance may become an issue with larger files.

Comment: @mklement0: Well, if I had a file with millions of lines I wouldn't use bash :)

Comment: @nsilent22: That's a good point, but I think it's fair to assume that when people tag questions `bash` they are _not_ usually looking for  a _pure Bash_ solution; rather, they usually mean: a solution involving standard Unix CLIs that can be called from Bash. @shijiexu, feel free to clarify.